# Setting Angular CLI to use scss does not work when generating a component

Tags: sass, angular-cli

I am creating a new project with angular cli with the following command:

`ng new project-cli --style=scss`

This command works fine for me I can see `src/style.scss` and `app/app.component.scss` are created. When I go to `angular-cli.json` I can also see that the `styleExt` is set to `scss`. but using:

`ng generate component header`

Creates a `header.component.css` instead of creating a `header.component.scss` file. Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? I am using:

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.1
node: 7.0.0
os: win32 x64
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your defaults set to in the angular/cli.json ?

If I don't have:

"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }

Mine will create a .css file ext. as well.

Comment: "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }

Comment: Those are my defaults